# Setting selection option using data attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

http://medfor.petersenuploads.co.uk/product.php/698/2/clear-ps-honey-jar-with-metal-screw-cap

Click on the Full Price tab and 'ADD' one of the options. This should set the values of the select boxes below but it doesn't change. The event is firing correctly but not changing the selected items.

Could this be a data type issue?

```
$('a.addspecific').live(
    'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log($(this).data('sterility'));
        console.log("IN");
        //Update dropdowns for JShop functionality
        $('#capacity').find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == $(this).data('capacity');  
        }).attr('selected',true);
        console.log($(this).data('capacity'));
        $('#sterility').find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == $(this).data('sterility');  
        }).attr('selected',true);
        console.log($(this).data('sterility'));
        $('#labeltype').find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == $(this).data('labeltype');  
        }).attr('selected',true);
        console.log($(this).data('labeltype'));
        $('#itemspercase').find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == $(this).data('itemspercase');  
        }).attr('selected',true);
        console.log($(this).data('itemspercase'));
        console.log("OUT");


    }
```

Comment: What exactly is it supposed to do ??

Comment: @Sushanth-- When you click on an item's Add button, the menus in the Product Selection box should all change to match that item.

Comment: Click the 'ADD' button in the tabs and it should set the options at the bottom to the correct settings so if you click the 50ml|Sterile|No Label|314 option it changes the dropdowns appropriately.

Comment: Instead of matching the data to the text of an option, wouldn't it be simpler to match it to the option's value? Then you could do `$("#capacity).val($(this).data('capacity'))`.

Comment: No. The value is not the same as the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The this context is fail, try it:

```
console.log("IN");
var thes = this;

$('#capacity').find("option").filter(function() {
     return $(this).text() == $(thes).data('capacity');  
}).attr('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.attr('selected',true);
```

Try using

```
.prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect